# When i insert the number into varchar2 attribute even i don't mention quotations tha number will takes that attribute why?

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL> `insert into emp(ename) values(7);`

Comment: This is probably MySQL, and what is happening here is implicit conversion of an integer literal to text.  While it might work, you should _not_ be relying on this behavior at all.  If you insert a value into a text column, the value should be _text_.

Comment: [Implicit data conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694)